# Prove every derived set is closed if this is the case for singleton sets

Tags: general-topology

Suppose that for each $x \in X$, the set of accumulation points of $\{ x \}$ is closed. Then for each $S \subseteq X$, the set of its accumulation points is closed.

This is the last part of exercise $D$ of chapter 1. I managed to solve all the previous points (not indicated here), but unfortunately this one remains open for me. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $S \subseteq X$ and $x \notin S'$. We need to find some open $U$ containing $x$ and such that $U$ misses $S'$.

$x \notin S'$ means that there exists some open $O$ containing $x$ such that $O \cap S \subseteq \{x\}$.

If $O \cap S = \emptyset$, we can pick $U = O$.

If $O \cap S = \{x\}$, then use that $X \setminus \{x\}'$ is open...

Comment: May I ask you another hint, please? :)

Comment: $x \notin \{x\}'$.

Comment: I am sorry, but I have probably entered in a self-confusing state.
Dear @Brandsma, I clearly see your answers but I continue to fail in putting all the pieces together...

Comment: Sleep on it. I have really given you all the ingredients, I think.

Comment: I'll follow your suggestion, thank you very much! :)

Comment: If $y \in U = O \cap (X \setminus \{x\}')$, where $U$ is indeed a neighbourhood for $x$, then $U$ intersects $S$ at most in $x$ (as $U \subseteq O$) and also, as $y \notin \{x\}'$ some neighbourhood $U_y$ of $y$ exists such that $U_y$ misses $x$. Now $U_y \cap U$ witnesses that $y \notin S'$. So $U \cap S' = \emptyset$, as required.

Comment: In the first case, $O\cap S=\varnothing$, how do you go from there to $O\cap S'=\varnothing$?

Comment: @PeptideChain that’s trivial from the definition.

Comment: I didn't get it until now, incredible. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if the following proof has any issue.

Notation:

- $A^d: \mbox{derived set of } A$
- $A^c: \mbox{closure of } A$

**Lemma**: $A \mbox{ is closed} \Leftrightarrow A^d \subset A$.

**Proof of the Lemma**:

- by definition of "closed": $A = A^c$
- by definition of "closure": $A^c = A\cup A^d$.

Therefore, $A$ is closed $\Leftrightarrow A = A\cup A^d \Leftrightarrow A^d\subset A$. $\blacksquare$

By the lemma, to show every $A^d$ is closed, it suffices to show that $A^{dd} \subset A^d$.

**Proof**:

By a property of derived set, $(A\cup B)^d = A^d \cup B^d$, we have

- $A^{dd} = \bigl(\bigcup_{x\in A} \{x\}\bigr)^{dd} = \bigcup_{x\in A} \{x\}^{dd}$
- $A^{d} = \bigl(\bigcup_{x\in A} \{x\}\bigr)^{d} = \bigcup_{x\in A} \{x\}^{d}$

Since each $\{x\}^d$ is closed, we have $\{x\}^{dd} \subset \{x\}^d \Rightarrow A^{dd} \subset A^d. \blacksquare$